# How to "write" a makefile which performs actions locally then on the SSH connected VM?

Tags: ssh, makefile, local

I'm discovering a new stack (Python/Flask, Makefile, Pip...) instead of my usual Node/Express, Npm, package.json...).
Sorry then if my question is bit dumb.

I'm currently writing a `Makefile` that copy (`scp`) file on my VM...

```
build:
    ... some actions...
    scp -v build.tar.gz root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:
```

... and then run automatically actions inside this very same `VM`...

```
    ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    docker load -i build.tar.gz
    docker run -dp 80:5000 myimg
```

However, this second part doesn't work.
My `makefile` does connect via SSH, but doesn't after use the two last `docker` instructions.

How to "pass" these instructions for a fully automated script?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a command to be run as arguments to `ssh`.  So you can use:

```
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx docker load -i build.tar.gz
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx docker run -dp 80:5000 myimg
```

There are other ways to do it as well.

Comment: More efficient but less readable is to have just one `ssh`; something like: `(echo docker load -l build.tar.gz; echo docker run -dp 80:5000 myimg) | ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`